# Foiling vectors with a matrix term

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Please excuse the simple question, but I can't seem to find anything relevant online. I have a term of the form: $$(\mathbf x-\mathbf y)^\top A(\mathbf x-\mathbf y)$$ and I can't figure out how to multiply these out to separate the terms as with FOILing with scalar variables as the matrix term is throwing me off. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Remember: *keep the order* when multiplying vectors or matrices! $A$ will appear in the middle of every term of the expansion:$\newcommand{x}{\mathbf x}\newcommand{y}{\mathbf y}$
$$(\x-\y)^\top A(\x-\y)=\x^\top A\x-\y^\top A\x-\x^\top A\y+\y^\top A\y$$

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, transpose can be distributed across subtraction. Secondly, you can distribute multiplication across subtraction too, as long as you maintain the order of any multiplications involved.

$\begin{aligned}
& (x-y)^TA(x-y) \\
&= (x^T-y^T)A(x-y)\\
&= (x^T-y^T)(Ax-Ay)\\
&= x^T(Ax -Ay)- y^T(Ax-Ay)\\
&= x^TAx - x^TAy - y^TAx + y^TAy
\end{aligned}$